LaTeX hooks have broken working code
This is an MWE distilled from a quite big system where the error messages are even  more cryptic.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MyStyle}

\begin{document}
\PopDefaultHookLabel

Case 0:

%\hello{}


Case 1:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 


Case 2:

%\usepackage{background}
%\backgroundsetup{                                                                                                      
%   scale=1,                                                                                
%   opacity=0.5,                                                                            
%   angle=0,                                                                                
%   contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{
%   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Black_square.jpg}}
%}    
         
\end{document}

And mystyle,sty is trivial.
\ProvidesPackage{MyStyle}[2018/02/14 Blah, Blah]

\newcommand\hello{"Hello square world"}

\usepackage{tikz}                      
              

Here, Case 0 returns
! LaTeX hooks Error: Missing.
(hooks)              The label 'MyStyle' was pushed but never popped.
(hooks)              Something is wrong."

without giving any indication of where or how to it. What do I need to add ?
THe other cases are simple examples of the sort of thing I'm doing in the main system. Here their specific errors are masked by the Case 0 error.  But in the live system I'm getting errors like:

(./Bridgesystem.aux) (C:/Miktex/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(C:/Miktex/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (C:/Miktex/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(C:/Miktex/tex/latex/00miktex/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
<No file pythontex-files-Bridgesystem/Bridgesystem.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.


(C:/Miktex/tex/latex/translations/dicts/translations-basic-dictionary-english.t
rsl)
geometry driver: auto-detecting
geometry detected driver: luatex


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 34--35

where I have no idea what has generated a sudden need for pythontex.
And the "underfull boxes" refer to a table in the subsequent (completely independent) input file which gives an error at the beginning of that file:

! Undefined control sequence. __"hook" env/tabular begin ->\Proportional \hook top


How do you think anybody can handle this without seeing code that produces the error?

Took me some time to format it

use three backticks or indent by four spaces (or use teh {} button in the editor) not > quotes for code blocks and error messgages

it is impossible to use your example to see the problem as MyStyle.sty is not available

OK. I'l try that thanks.

the underfull box warnings are due to mis-placed \\ such as the one you show after case 2:

Is \end{document} really in your sty file???

The \ aren;t in the original code.  Ony the MWE.  It was quite an effort to isolate what seems to be the core issue of hooks.

THe end document wasn't there.  The luatex run hung with a question amrk so I shoved it in to see if oit would have any effect, And never took it out.

There are hundreds of lines in the real style file.  So it was really difficlult to reproduce the exact problem.  It seems fairly clear that something has added hooks that I never had,  But Ive moved from Windows 10 to 11 and reinstalled Miktex without changing my working code.

That's what I tried to do - I binary chopped  until I got a single error about a hook, And noting about python or underfull boxes in a different input file.  I was hoping if I could fix the hook problem in the MWE it world give me some clue as to what to do next,  Because now I have none - I've never had a need for hooks.

why don't you simply remove the \PopDefaultHookLabel?

@UlrikeFischer Thanks Ulrike Because I'm totally ignorant!!! How do I do that?

But if we compile this, the error is Extra \PopDefaultHookLabel.  So we can't debug code you haven't shown us.  Perhaps it would help if you explained what you were trying to do, instead of assuming we can debug from a cryptic error message.

@Teepeemm If I could even get rid of that error I might have a handle on what to do next.  But I don;t see why the MWE is generating that error.

go with your cursor to the place behind \PopDefaultHookLabel in your example (just behind begin document) and then hit backspace until the command is gone?

In a new, empty project, copy and paste the files you have here.  You can ask about errors that demonstrates.  Asking about other errors doesn't really make sense.  (Unless you think that me saying you have a typo on line 119 of MyStyle.sty is helpful.)

Your edit appears wrong (and means my answer now does not make sense) the code posted does not produce the error that you show. Please edit to correct the example so that it matches the error message shown.

Your code produces
! LaTeX hooks Error: Missing \PopDefaultHookLabel.
(hooks)              The label 'MyStyle' was pushed but never popped.
(hooks)              Something is wrong.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \end{document}


(you omitted the final part of the error message). Contrary to "without giving any indication of where" the full message pinpoints the cause of the error being the \end{document} on line 7 of MyStyle.sty In fact your example could be simplified to
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MyStyle}

\begin

as none of your document is read as the run stopped at \end{document} in the package.
Deleting that, then you get the error with your original document
! LaTeX hooks Error: Extra \PopDefaultHookLabel.
(hooks)              This command will be ignored.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \PopDefaultHookLabel
                        
? 

which again highlights the exact line with the error, you are popping a stack that you have not used. Deleting that line the document runs without error.
So despite the title "LaTeX hooks have broken working code" both errors are due to errors in the document which could not have worked without error on an older format with hout the package hooks, although the exact error messages would have been slightly different.

OK. Thanks guys appreciate the help.  I'll clean the MWE and if there are further errors I'll repost from scratch.

It's sorted.  You got me back on the right track - THANKS.  I'd switched to Windows 11 finally and reinstalled Miktex. Suddenly these messages about python and hooks started appearing in what had been working code. Not at all like the error messagges I'm used to.  But it turned  out that I'd put a hline into a tabular and broken some lines the  working code.  Debugging is much easier when you look in the right place.
